# Two column enumerate revtex

Tags: enumerate, multicol, revtex

We have a list of small items

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\item c
\item d
\end{enumerate}
```

which we would like to typeset as such

```
1. a             3. c
2. b             4. d
```

Normally we could use the `multicol` package.  However if we are forced to use the `revtex4-1` document class, we cannot use `multicol` as it is explicitly listed to be incompatible.  How can we typeset this nonetheless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the enumeration should go from left to right, the `tasks` package is perhaps the right choice (but certainly not the only one, of course).

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}


\usepackage{tasks}


\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task First
\task Second
\task Third
\task Fourth
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]